# How to Record Audio in Windows Store 8.1 ".wav" C#

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps

I am trying to record audio in .wav, but I could not I have tried many thing like NAudio, MediaCapture and other stuff but could not success can some one help me to record audio in .wav file in windows store 8.1.!

Comment: I am flagging this as off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the MediaCapture sample?

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622